# PyCharm IDE Issue "'run 'main ''action not available while PyCharm is updating indices"

Tags: pycharm

I've been trying to learn python with the PyCharm IDE, I can not run file because of an infinity updating indices.It's a real shame since I can't progress if I cant run a file. Could someone please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Wait until the indices finish updating? It usually doesn't take *that* long, you can monitor progress in the lower-right-hand corner of the IDE.

Comment: you have to learn python with a simple editor, like notepad! why? because people did the same mistake and think that java is eclipse!

Comment: how long does the updating  actually last?

Comment: @Abdelouahab, that makes absolutely no sense

Comment: @PadraicCunningham this is a personal advice, because using an advanced IDE, will kill the learning curve, from its beginning! for example, relaying on calltips will make the user forget what is `dir()`

Comment: Are you using a normal hard disk or an SSD?  If you use an SSD while you're on PyCharm (or any IntelliJ IDE), you can get a significant speed increase.  After all, indexing is I/O bound; you can't really speed that up without an SSD.

Answer (score 0):

Are there autogenerated or downloaded files in your project folder?
If so, IDE would reindex them every time.

In such case, I would recommend to put those files in a subfolder inside the project folder and exclude them using the following method:

To exclude the folder from indexing, mark this folder as Excluded in the 
File | Setting | Project | Project Structure |  | Click Excluded

This solved my problem while I was downloading a lot of files and everytime I opened pycharm it was indexing and taking a lot of time.